# dynamically resizing image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a banner, and it's a certain size. It has decorations on it.
I also have my whole website style sheet based on percentages on the page. I want to keep it this way.
However, is there a way to dynamically resize my banner image? So if I shrink the webpage down, it does not omit any part of the banner?

Comment: do you have a demo? we can barely understand what's going on here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi is very simple without jquery you can do this only css

i give you code

**css part**

```
.imgresize{
    width:50%;
}
.imgtag{
    width:100%;
}
```

**html part**

```
<div class="imgresize">
<img src="https://www.google.pt/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="google" class="imgtag" />
</div>
```

and [live demo now click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/aJdmu/1/)

http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/aJdmu/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of blurry, but to resize properly an image you can play on the `width` or the `height` value (or both) of an

```
<img width="width_value" src="img_src" />
```

tag for example. The browser will keep the proportions of the image if you only change one attribute. Changing these values using Javascript is easy and this should not alter your layout.